# Angular using a promise for Interaction with a popup

Tags: angularjs, oauth, oauth-2.0, popup, angular-promise

I'm new to angular, services and definitely to promises. I have this bit of code in a service which works on its own, but it's messy. I want to put the whole thing into a promise if possible as that would make it super workable.

I'm doing oAuth authentication with google. The flow is:

1. User clicks "Login with Google"
2. a popup opens that redirects to Googles 'Approve' screen.
3. User clicks 'approve' and gets redirected (in the popup) back to my redirect page (including Googles approval code).
4. My redirect page takes the code he got from google and sends that to my Backend server to redeem the code from Google to exchange it for an access token.
5. My server redeems the code and gets the profile info from google (and  logs the user in) and returns a user object that my angular app can use.
6. The returned user object (still arriving in the popup) gets given back to the opener of the popup, and the popup closes.
7. The user is now logged in in my app.

As you will see from the code, I create (temporary) functions in the sender window as callbacks for the popup window. This works, but feels messy. Also I don't know how to put this whole thing in a promise so eventually I can just call the services as:

```
oAuthService.login().then(
  function(){/*rejoice, we made it*/}, 
  function(){/*Error logging*/};`
```

Here's my code:

```
'use strict';
var loginServices = angular.module('loginServices', []);

loginServices.service('oAuthService', ['$http', '$q', 'store', '$rootScope', '$window',
  function($http, $q, store, $rootScope, $window){

    //todo: Put data in settings file
    var oAuthRequest = {
      endpoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
      clientId: '705441731416-iqd7ubbi7so12k4rvj5pr0frdpoqfo4p.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      scope: 'email profile',
      state: 'MyToken123',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost/loginadmin/web/oAuthRedirect',
      responseType: 'code',
      approvalPrompt: 'force'
    };

    this.oAuthGetApproval = function(){
      //Create Callback functions for the popup
      //This will get called after step 5 completed server side
      window.oAuthUserLogin = function(user, sender){
        store.set('currentUser', user);
        $rootScope.setCurrentUser(user);
        sender.close();
        sender.angular.element('#ctrl').scope().apply();
        //cleanup
        window.oAuthUserLogin = undefined;
        window.oAuthUserLoginError = undefined;
      }

      //Err callback
      window.oAuthUserLoginError = function(data, sender){
        console.log('Error');
        console.log(data);
        sender.close();
        //cleanup
        window.oAuthUserLogin = undefined;
        window.oAuthUserLoginError = undefined;
      }

      //Open popup (Step 1 and 2 in description)
      var uri = oAuthRequest.endpoint
          + '?scope=' + oAuthRequest.scope
          + '&state=' + oAuthRequest.state
          + '&redirect_uri=' + oAuthRequest.redirectUri
          + '&response_type=' + oAuthRequest.responseType
          + '&client_id=' + oAuthRequest.clientId
          + '&approval_prompt=' + oAuthRequest.approvalPrompt;

      $window.open(uri, '', "top=100,left=100,width=500,height=500");
    };

    //This gets called the popup (Step 4 in description)
    this.oAuthCompleteLogin = function(code){
      $http.post('http://localhost/covlelogin/web/api/oauth-login', { code: code })
          .success(function (data){
            $window.opener.oAuthUserLogin(data, window);
          })
          .error(function(data){
            $window.opener.oAuthUserLoginError(data, window);
          })
    }

  }]);
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out myself. I'm now using `$interval` to check if the popup has returned something useful yet or if the popup got closed.

```
'use strict';
var loginServices = angular.module('loginServices', []);

loginServices.service('oAuthService', ['$http', '$q', 'store', '$rootScope', '$window', '$interval',
  function($http, $q, store, $rootScope, $window, $interval){

    //todo: Put data in settings file
    var oAuthRequest = {
      endpoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
      clientId: '705441731416-iqd7ubbi7so12k4rvj5pr0frdpoqfo4p.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      scope: 'email profile',
      state: 'MyToken123',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost/loginadmin/web/oAuthRedirect',
      responseType: 'code',
      approvalPrompt: 'force'
    };

    this.oAuthGetApproval = function(){
      var q = $q.defer();
      //Open popup
      var uri = oAuthRequest.endpoint
          + '?scope=' + oAuthRequest.scope
          + '&state=' + oAuthRequest.state
          + '&redirect_uri=' + oAuthRequest.redirectUri
          + '&response_type=' + oAuthRequest.responseType
          + '&client_id=' + oAuthRequest.clientId
          + '&approval_prompt=' + oAuthRequest.approvalPrompt;

      var popup = $window.open(uri, '', "top=100,left=100,width=500,height=500");

      var popupChecker = $interval(function(){

        if (window.oAuthUser != undefined){
          //The popup put returned a user! Resolve!
          q.resolve(window.oAuthUser);
          popup.close();
          $interval.cancel(popupChecker);
          //Save and apply user locally
          store.set('currentUser', window.oAuthUser);
          $rootScope.setCurrentUser(window.oAuthUser);
          //Cleanup
          window.oAuthUser = undefined;
        }else if (popup.closed){
          $interval.cancel(popupChecker);
          console.log("Error logging in.");
          q.reject();
        }
        console.log('tick');
      }, 1000)

      return q.promise;
    };

    this.oAuthCompleteLogin = function(code){
      $http.post('http://localhost/covlelogin/web/api/oauth-login', { code: code })
          .success(function (data){
            $window.opener.oAuthUser = data;
          })
          .error(function(data){
            $window.close();
          })
    }

  }]);
```

Calling this service is now a simple matter of doing this:

```
oAuthService.oAuthGetApproval().then(
      function(user){
        console.log("Logged in as " + user.name);
      },
      function(){
        console.log("Login did not go well.");
      });
```